# Cannot make HTTP request using ESP8266

Tags: python, http-get, esp8266

Since few days i 've tried to make simple web app combine with ESP8266 module. Now I get stuck on sending HTTP request from ESP (configured as client) to my application or on any other server.

When I try make GET request to some website every time I get Bad request . This are my commands (I use python script to accelerate prosess of making connection.)

```
send_command('AT+CWMODE=1\n', wifi)

send_command('AT+CIPMUX=0\n', wifi)

send_command('AT+CWJAP="my_network","password"\n', wifi)

send_command('AT+CIPSTART="TCP","onet.pl",80\r\n', wifi,2)

request = r"HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: onet.pl\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"

send_command('AT+CIPSEND=' + str(len(request)) + '\n', wifi)

send_command(request,wifi,5)
```

Send_command function:

```
def send_command(komenda, serial_name,czas=1):

while serial_name.writable() == 0:
    pass

serial_name.write((komenda).encode())

while serial_name.out_waiting:
    pass

while serial_name.in_waiting == 0:#<= len(komenda)+4:
    pass

while serial_name.readable() == 0:
    pass
res = (serial_name.read(serial_name.in_waiting))

if czas == 1:
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    time.sleep(2)
if serial_name.in_waiting:
    res= res+ (serial_name.read(serial_name.in_waiting))

print (res.decode('utf-8','ignore'))

serial_name.reset_input_buffer()
serial_name.reset_output_buffer()

return res.decode('utf-8','ignore')
```

And the response is :

`+IPD,160:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Dreamlab Accelerator
Date: Sat, 10 Jun 2017 16:32:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 166
Connection: close`

I will be gratefull for any suggestions what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another day I solved this problem.
This is my solution (maybe it will be helpful for someoone else)

1. Upgrade the esp8266 firmware to version 0.9.5.2
2. Each command sould be ended with signs '\r\n'
3. Every command should be normal string (not raw string as in request command in the post above).